# Creating a Graph DB in Neo4j from large CSV file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am relatively new to neo4j so I apologised if this seems trivial.
I am trying to import data from a csv file with quite a large amount of rows, around 2.5 Million rows using the Neo4j desktop app, running it in the Neo4j browser.
The contents of the file follow the format:

```
entity1, relation, entity2
entity1, relation, entity3
...
entityN, relation, entityM
```

I have tried using the query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///all_triplets.csv' AS row
MERGE (entity1:Entity {name:row.entity1} )
MERGE (entity2:Entity {name:row.entity2} )
MERGE (entity1) - [:RELATION {name:row.relation}] -> (entity2)
```

but I get a MemoryPoolOutOfMemoryError after an hour running, so modify my query to run in 'batches' to free up memory while running:

```
:auto LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///all_triplets.csv' AS row
CALL {
WITH row
MERGE (entity1:Entity {name:row.entity1} )
MERGE (entity2:Entity {name:row.entity2} )
MERGE (entity1) - [:RELATION {name:row.relation}] -> (entity2)
} IN TRANSACTIONS
```

but the query runs for hours which I dont think is being implemented correctly, So what I need is to be able to store this information in a DB so that I can extract the node embeddings after (i dont need to be able to visualize the graph). Is there a better way to load a large list like this? importing 2.5M records should not take that long to be honest, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/#_implications_on_indexes) (which also creates an index as a by-product) on `:Entity(name)`, to make the `MERGE`s of your nodes more efficient. For instance:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT Entity_name FOR (e:Entity) REQUIRE e.name IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Can you point or show where that would go in the last query I provided? right before before MERGE?

Comment: You only need to create the constraint or index once. So run that by query all by itself. Afterwards, neo4j automatically updates the index as needed.

Comment: can you elaborate on why using a constraint would speed things up? im not very familiar with its use.

Comment: Creating a uniqueness constraint does not directly speed anything up, but since it creates an index for you it does speed up associated `MATCH`es. Also, a uniqueness constraint will [prevent concurrent `MERGE`s from creating duplicate nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76211576/974731).

Comment: Alright, thank you! Using a constraint and setting the value for db.memory.transaction.total.max to be 2GB (the default was too low) I was able to run the query in a matter of minutes. @cybersam